# Trumpet Mouthpiece for Playing High Notes

Tags: mouthpieces

Any suggestions for an effective trumpet mouthpiece to be able to play above G (above the staff)? Currently using Schilke 14A4A but doesn't quite make it.

Comment: Hi! I'm afraid gear recommendations aren't among the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Despite what manufacturers would have you believe, there's no magic bullet/new golf clubs/shiny equipment answer to this. You can't **buy** a quick answer to this problem.

The actual answer is to choose a mouthpiece that's comfortable for you and then commit hours of practise over months and years doing flexibility and range expanding exercises.

And get a trumpet-playing expert to review your progress periodically to make sure you're not developing bad habits.